# tomar valores de un void e imprimirlos en una función JAVA

Tags: java

Tengo una duda cómo puedo imprimir los valores de diferentes public static void? En Java

Digamos tengo

```
public static void Carro (int x, int y, int r) {

  r=x+y;
}
```

Y en otra tengo

```
public static void Motos ( int x, int y, int r) {

  r=x+y;
}
```

quisiera hacerle un `System.out.println` a los resultados de las operaciones de carro y motos, pero desde una función, quisiera saber si se pueden tomar los resultados e imprimirlos aparte en una función o en otro void

Comment: Literalmente `void` significa que la función no devuelve absolutamente nada. Vacío. Si quieres imprimir algo de esa función, tienes que hacerlo dentro de la función. O hacer que la función devuelva algo. Por cierto, absolutamente nada te impide hacer un `System.out.println(x+y);` **DENTRO** de la función, pero siendo void, no vas a poder sacarlo de ahí facilmente (y no deberías hacerlo tampoco).

Answer (score 2):

Una función declarada como `void` no devuelve nada (*void* significa literalmente *nulo, vacío*). Por tanto no puedes imprimir el resultado de una función/método declarado *void*. Por supuesto nada te impide usar `System.out.println` **dentro** de la función.

Por otro lado, el parámetro `r` es totalmente innecesario: en Java, las asignaciones a parámetros no tienen efecto fuera de la función. Por ejemplo:

```
static int suma(int a, int b) {
    a = a + b; // sobreescribo el parámetro a
    return a;
}

public static void main (String ...args) {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 2;
    int c = suma(a, b);
    System.out.println("La suma de "+ a + " y " + b + " da " + c);
}
```

Este código [muestra](https://tio.run/##VY/PCoMwDMbve4rgSXHrYbCT7A12cy@Q2iJ1WqWNggyfvYud@2OgJPklfPna4ISnRj1CqFr0Hu7aEzwPwOEJyVRgLIEfO0zXAo@xl9m2swbCFTAHWXyJ0zQ6C/gmyyGmYZQty22qU28UdGgspCU5Y2sQQqCr/b9yvMjql2KHJKPzHlWMokk2KLPfrJw96U70I4mBr1Br0@SGcRWUhiRn/RwSmPnxF2KtMDZV9rG/hPAC) "La suma de 5 y 2 da 7", porque `a` no se ve afectado, ya que lo que se pasa a la función `suma` es **una copia** de `a`.

Answer (score 1):

No es posible realizar la acción que quieres siendo que es un **void**. Puedes hecharle una leída a [este post](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.es/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=430:metodos-en-java-tipo-procedimiento-void-y-tipo-funcion-return-definicion-invocacion-cu00624b&catid=68&Itemid=188), cito la parte que podría interesarte:

> **b) Métodos tipo procedimiento:** son métodos que realizan ciertas
> operaciones sin devolver un valor u objeto concreto. Un método es tipo
> procedimiento si comienza con la palabra clave void (que traducido del
> inglés viene siendo “vacío” o “nulo”). En estos casos podemos decir
> que el tipo de retorno es void. De forma genérica:
>
> ```
> /* Ejemplo - aprenderaprogramar.com */
>
> //Comentario descriptivo de qué hace el método
>
> public void nombreDelMétodo (tipo parámetro1, tipo parámetro2…) {    
>     Código del método
> }
> ```
>
> En general un método con tipo de retorno void no llevará sentencia
> return, aunque en Java se permite que un método de este tipo incluya
> la sentencia return;. Si ocurre esto, la sentencia da lugar a que el
> método finalice en ese punto sin ejecutar ninguna línea más de código.
> Solo tiene sentido su uso asociado a que se cumplan ciertas
> condiciones.

Dicho esto el void no regresará un valor como tal ya que como su misma palabra lo indica retorna un "void => vacio".

Las formas que puedes utilizar para mostrar el valor varia según lo que necesites hacer, podrías modificar algunas líneas de tu código.

Podrías mostrar el valor dentro del método:

```
public static void Carro(int x, int y, int r) {
    r=x+y;
    System.out.print("valor" + r);
}
```

O modificar tu método para que retorne el valor:

```
public static int Carro(int x, int y, int r) {
    r=x+y;
    return r;
}
```

O bien si no necesitas la variable r para hacer ninguna otra operación podrías reducir tu código a:

```
public static int Carro(int x, int y) {
    return x+y;
}
```

Y finalmente mostrar el valor desde otro método.

Espero la información sea de ayuda. Saludos ;)